# Null handling in ENUM switch

Tags: java, enums

I've noticed that there's a potential pitfall regarding null for switch on enums.

The asymmetry is regarding the possible range of values for an enum versus range of values which are accepted by switch.

```
public class SwitchEnumPitfall {
private static enum MyEnum { FOO, BAR }
public static void main(final String... args) {
      final MyEnum e = null;
     switch (e) { // throws NullPointerException
         //case null: System.err.println("null"); break; // wouldn't compile
          case FOO: System.err.println("FOO"); break;
          case BAR: System.err.println("BAR"); break;
      }
   }
 }
```

The int value to switch on is determined by invoking the method Enum.ordinal(). The following code demonstrates that the ordinals start at zero.

```
 public enum EnumOrdinals {
 FOO, BAR;
 public static void main(final String... args) {
     System.out.println(FOO.ordinal());
     System.out.println(BAR.ordinal());
   }
}
```

That means, mapping null to 0 wouldn't be a good idea. A switch on the first enum value would be indistinguishible from null. Maybe it would've been a good idea to start counting the ordinals for enums at 1. However it hasn't been defined like that, and this definition can not be changed.

Why hasn't it been defined like that?

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: Just want to share info . As suggested posted answer

Comment: that's why it's a good practice to use another "NONE" or "UNKNOWN" enum constant

Comment: @L.Möller but here the question in about creating or having enum reference `null`, how it will matter by having 'NONE' or any other enum constant. ?

Comment: @rajuGT you not as easily tempted to pass `null` in the first place like this. but you're right that it's not an answer to the question (thus I wrote it as comment)

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple. Wherever null is dereferenced, a NullPointerException is thrown. It's only explicit methods checking explicitely with if (x != null) that can avoid null from being derefernced. If switch would check its enum argument for being null and handle this special case, that would've broken with the philosophy of Java.

However, Java is not only the Java Programming Language. It's also the Java Virtual Machine. And you can run other programming languages on that as well. The decision to start counting enums at 0 has made Java enums running on the JVM implicitely incompatible with possible scripting languages that treat null as zero and start their enum ordinals at 1.